# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined Laravel + Whatsapp-web js

Tags: laravel, node-modules, laravel-mix

I tried to use whatspp-web js in laravel 8 Application and after all configurations I run the `npm run dev` and its shows this result.

[image]

this is my webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
mix.js('resources/js/whatsapp.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
mix.webpackConfig({
plugins: [
    new NodePolyfillPlugin()
],
target:'node',
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.FLUENTFFMPEG_COV': false
    })
]
})
```

here is the whatsapp.js file which i created inside of resources/js folder

```
// Import the WhatsApp Web JS package
import { Client } from 'whatsapp-web.js';

// Create a WhatsApp client
const client = new Client();

// Log in to WhatsApp using a QR code
client.on('qr', (qr) => {
 // Display the QR code, for example, in an image element with id "qrCode"
document.getElementById('qrCode').src = qr;
});

client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('WhatsApp client is ready');
});

client.initialize();
```

this is how i use the script in .blade file

```
 <img id="qrCode" alt="QR Code" src="">
 <script src="{{ mix('js/whatsapp.js') }}"></script>
```

This is how browser console shows error
[image: This is how browser console shows error]

and its shows `whatsapp.js:88465 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in compiled whatsapp.js file `public/js/whatsapp.js`

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this issue please.!